# Null pointer exception for google api Classpath

Tags: java, google-api, classpath

I'm a little bit new with Java, so I apologize in advance. In a Google API [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample), a `.credentials` file is loaded from the method `getResourceAsStream` and the path as `"/client_secret.json"`. From here, I learned that this `getResourceAsStream` get's the file from the CLASS path, which confuses me because my `src` directory structure looks like the following.

`.
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── GmailQuickstart.java
    └── resources
        └── client_secret.json`

When I open a new project (using a servlet) and try to load this, I'm finding this `InputStream` is null. The `src` directory of the following project looks like so:

`.
└── main
    ├── java
    │   ├── GmailQuickstart.java
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── something
    │   │       └── HelloWorldServlet.java
    │   └── somepackage
    │       └── Thing.java
    ├── resources
    │   └── client_sercret.json
    └── webapp
        └── WEB-INF
            └── web.xml`

I've tried changing it to what I though would be the same CLASSPATH, but I guess that's not correct. From the previous advice, I've also tried `"/main/java/resources/client_secret.json"`. Obviously I'm not doing something right here.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add resources folder to your classpath.
If you are using eclipse, right click your project, configure build path, add your resources folder in Source tab.